# How do you convert the first word of a phrase to all upper case?

Tags: java

I do not know the phrase that the user inputs into my program and I need to capitalize the entire first word.

This is code I have tried to use.

```
System.out.println(p1.toUpperCase(0, p1.charAt(" ")));
```

The error I receive is, "The method charAt(int) in type String is not applicable for the agruments (String)." I am not sure how else to upper case so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your words are separated by space, you can use the following way to make your first word uppercase:

```
String str = "This is a space separated string";

String newString = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ")).toUpperCase() + 
                   str.substring(str.indexOf(" "));
```

Note that, [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method takes an index, and returns the character at that index. You need to use [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) which gives the first index of the passed sequence, or character.

In the above code:

`str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "))` returns the first word in your string, and invoking `toUpperCase()` on the returned string converts the string to uppercase.
Then you concatenate with the remaining string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `capitalize` or `capitalizeFully` method from the `WordUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang3.text`.

For more details have a look [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html).